# Find the sum from 1st element to the 30th element of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n$ is the sequence defined by $$a_n = \left[\frac{n^2+8n+10}{n+9}\right]$$
where $[x]$ is the largest integer that doesn't exceed $x$.
  Find $$\sum_{n=1}^{30} a_n$$

" Where $[x]$ is the largest integer that doesn't exceed $x$. " what does it mean? I haven't tried much, since i don't even understand the question...

$a_1= 19/10;\; a_2 = 30/13;\;a_3 = 43/12;,\ldots$

Comment: $\frac{n^2 + 8n +10}{n+9}= n-1 + \frac{19}{n+9}$ . So the thing behave as n for n less than 11 and n-1 for n greater than 10

Comment: $a_1 \ne \frac {19}{10}$.  $\frac {19}{10}= 1.9$ and $1.9$ is not an integer.  $...-1< 0< 1< \frac {19}{10} < 2< 3<...$ so $a_1 = [\frac {19}{10} ]=1$ which is the largest integer that does not exceed $1.9$.  The integers $2$ and larger all exceed $1.9$ and the integers $1$ and less do not.  $1$ is the largest integer that does not exceed $1.9$ so $[1.9] = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $[\;]$ which called "floor function" or "integer part" is defined as follows:
For a real $x$, write $x$ in the form $x=n+f$ where $n$ is an integer and $f$ is so that $0\leq f<1$, then $[x]=n$. Specially, if $0\leq x<1$ then $[x]=0$. Also for negative numbers like $-3.14=-4+0.86$, thus $[-3.14]=-4$

For an answer to the question see
[If $a_n=\left[\frac{n^2+8n+10}{n+9}\right]$, find $ \sum_{n=1}^{30} a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3267245/338156)

Comment: In positive numbers [3.14] = 3. But [ -3.14] = -4?

Comment: since $-4 \le -3.14 < -3$ then all the integers $-3$ and larger exceed $-3.14$ and the largest integer that *doesn't* exceed is $-4$.   So $[-3.14] = -4$.  It means *exactly* what it says it means.

Comment: For every real $x$, whether positive of negative, there is a *unique* integer $n$ so that $n \le x < n+1$ and $[x] = n$.  If $x$ is negative then $n$ is negative.  $|x| \ge |n|$.  So yes,  $[-3.14]$ is so that $-4 \le -3.14 < -3$ and $[-3.14] = -4$ and $|-3.14| < |-4|$.